# Convergence in Probability to Zero Implies a.s. Boundedness Eventually

Tags: probability-theory

I am currently trying to show whether the following statement is valid:

**Claim:** Let $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n \to 0$ in probability as $n \to \infty$. Then there exists $M>0$ such that $|X_n| \leq M$ a.e. "eventually" in the sense that

$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} \mathbb{P}\left( \sup_{n > k}|X_n| > M \right) = 0.$$

So far, I have been able to show that this results hold for a subsequence $\{X_{n_j}\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. I am having a hard time trying to generalize this to the entire sequence. Intuitively I feel like the claim should be true, however my intuition in probability theory has often proven to be wrong.

Please let me know if I can provide anymore information, any hints or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0 \Leftrightarrow$ $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(\left | X_n \right |> \epsilon)=0 \Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon>0, \forall \delta>0$ $\exists k$ s.t. $\forall n \geq k $ we have $\mathbb{P}(\left | X_n \right |>\epsilon)< \delta$ which means $\mathbb{P}(\sup_{n \geq k} \left | X_n \right |>\epsilon)<\delta$.

On the other hand, $\lim_{k\to\infty} \mathbb{P}\left( \sup_{n > k}|X_n| > M \right) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists l$ s.t. $k \geq l$ implies $\mathbb{P}\left( \sup_{n > k}|X_n| > M \right)< \epsilon$.

Do you see why we have the first statement is stronger? Hint: Fix $\epsilon$ as $M$ and rename $\delta$ as $\epsilon$ in the first statement.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much!

Comment: From the RHS of the first iff in the first statement, could we conclude that $X_n$ is eventually a.e. bounded without looking at the supremum in the first place? i.e. is it true that $X_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0$ iff for $M>0$ fixed and $\delta>0$ arbitrary there exists $k(M, \delta)>0$ such that $n>k \implies \mathbb{P}(\left | X_n \right |> M)=0$? Or is there a specific reason why we should be interested in looking at the supremum? I am doing so because my lecture notes and textbook seem to always prove statements with supremums.

Comment: Yes you can say that. The definition of boundedness is sometimes stated with supremum, sometimes not. But the two are evidently equivalent: $X_n \leq M \forall n \Leftrightarrow \sup_n X_n \leq M$.

Comment: Wait @FraGrechi , about this last comment, suppose you have a sequence of independent Gaussians $X_n \sim N(0,1/n^2)$, $X_n$ converges $0$, but you never have $P(X_k>M)=0$, no matter how big you take $k$ and $M$, you really need a limit here.